# how to draw a grade segment with tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf

how can I change this segment in a grade segment? I attach the figure

[image]

This is my code:

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{angles,quotes}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,arrows.meta}
\pagestyle{empty}
\newcommand{\degre}{\ensuremath{^\circ}}
% \renewcommand{\rmdefault}{phv}
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{phv}

\usepackage{sansmath}

\definecolor{uququq}{rgb}{0.25098039215686274,0.25098039215686274,0.25098039215686274}
\tikzset{
    quote/.style={{|[width=2mm]}-{|[width=2mm]}}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[> = stealth]
\coordinate (a) at (1,2);
\coordinate (b) at (7,2);


\draw[black,step=1cm] (0,0) grid +(15cm,4cm);


\draw[ultra thick, line width=1.25mm, black, |-|]  (a) -- (b);
\draw[color=black] (0.5, 1.5) node {\Huge $A$};
\draw[color=black] (7.5, 1.5) node {\Huge $B$};


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The decoration `ticks` of the library `decorations.pathreplacing` is a way. Also, you can design your own decoration with the library `decorations.markings`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\pagecolor{yellow!30}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[lightgray] (-1,-1) grid (5,4);
\path (4,0) coordinate (A) node[below right]{$A$};
\path (0,3) coordinate (B) node[above left]{$B$};
    
\draw[ultra thick]  (A) -- (B);
\draw[ultra thick, decoration={ticks,amplitude=4pt,
segment length=1cm},decorate,red] (A) -- (B);
\end{tikzpicture}


\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\begin{tikzpicture}[decoration={
markings,% switch on markings
mark=% actually add a mark
between positions 0 and 1 step 1cm
with {
\fill[blue] (0,0) circle(3pt);
%\draw[red] (0,-2pt)--(0,2pt);    // try if you want ticks
}}]
\draw[lightgray] (-1,-1) grid (5,4);
\draw[postaction={decorate}] (4,0)--(0,3)|-cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!! :)

Answer (score 4):

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{angles,quotes}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\pagestyle{empty}
\newcommand{\degre}{\ensuremath{^\circ}}
% \renewcommand{\rmdefault}{phv}
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{phv}

\usepackage{sansmath}

\definecolor{uququq}{rgb}{0.25098039215686274,0.25098039215686274,0.25098039215686274}
\tikzset{
    quote/.style={{|[width=2mm]}-{|[width=2mm]}}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[> = stealth]
\coordinate (a) at (1,2);
\coordinate (b) at (7,2);


\draw[black,step=1cm] (0,0) grid +(15cm,4cm);

\draw[ultra thick, line width=1.25mm, black, |-|]  (a) -- (b);
\draw[ultra thick, decoration={ticks,amplitude=8pt,
 segment length=1cm},decorate] (a) -- (b);
\draw[color=black] (0.5, 1.5) node {\Huge $A$};
\draw[color=black] (7.5, 1.5) node {\Huge $B$};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]